# How to add multiple class parse objects to a relation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

in my project I have a user relation for the key userPosts. I want to add to this relation different objects with different class names, something like this:

```
PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:selectedCategory];
// doing stuff with the object
[object save];
PFRelation *relation = [PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"userPosts"];
[relation addObject:post];
[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to execute this code it throws me a runtime error saying basically that I can only add objects to a relation with one class name.
How do I override/fix it? Thanks